# generate a certificate request in c++

Tags: c++, openssl, certificate

I'm a beginner in the cryptographic environment and I'd like to do something basic.

As the title says, I want to generate a certificate request, then send it to a CA to generate the certificate and then I want to revoke it. I want to do all this using C++. 
I have already generated a CA using the openssl library using Command Prompt, but now I want to work in Visual Studio (C++) to do the jobs above using the CA generated this way.

I have searched on the Internet which library is most suitable for this kind of jobs but I can't seem to get to a result. Could somebody point me in the right direction? ( some examples would be appreciated, because the msdn website hasn't helped me very much so far ). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend <strike>[Keyczar (deprecated)](https://github.com/google/keyczar)</strike> [Google's Tink](https://github.com/google/tink) and [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). If you feel more adventurous, there's [sslpkix](https://github.com/jweyrich/sslpkix/), which is a C++ wrapper for handling digital certificates using OpenSSL. Although it's functional, its API is not quite complete and is likely to change. It's also lacking documentation and a VS project. You may find it useful as a study resource though (check the test case).